# express node cannot read content of undefined

Tags: node.js, express

i am using post request here

```
app.post('/api/notes', (req, res, next) => {
  const clientReq = req.body.content;
  if (!clientReq) {
    res.status(400).send({ error: `bruh you need content smh`});
  }
  fs.readFile(dataPath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({error: `bro unexpected error`})
      }
    const wholeData = JSON.parse(data);
    const id = wholeData.id++;
    wholeData.notes[id] = {id: id, content: content};
  })
  fs.writeFile(dataPath, JSON.stringify(wholeData, null, 2), 'utf-8', err => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    res.status(201).json({content: content});
  })
})
```

however when i type in command line post :3000/api/notes content=" blah"

im getting error i cannot read content of udnefined

Answer (score 1):

Here you are missing `body-parser`. When you don't use that you get the raw request, and your body and headers are not in the root object of request parameter . You will have to individually manipulate all the fields.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api/notes', (req, res, next) => {
  const clientReq = req.body;
  console.log(req.body)
  if (!clientReq) {
    res.status(400).send({ error: `bruh you need content smh`});
  }
  fs.readFile(dataPath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({error: `bro unexpected error`})
      }
    const wholeData = JSON.parse(data);
    const id = wholeData.id++;
    wholeData.notes[id] = {id: id, content: content};
  })
  fs.writeFile(dataPath, JSON.stringify(wholeData, null, 2), 'utf-8', err => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    res.status(201).json({content: content});
  })
})
```